# How to scroll to middle (50%) of page

Tags: jquery, scroll

Without using the popular scrollTo plugin, how can I scroll to the vertical middle (50%) of the page/div?

Comment: None of those worked I'm afraid. To explain further: I have a div that's 500px tall and it's contents are 1000px tall. I need the div's scroll position to be exactly 50%/middle of the div. Sounds easy, but I've been at it for hours and no joy. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to scroll inside a div and not scroll TO the div .. I updated my answer

Answer (score 4):

This scrolls the internal scroll of a div to it's vertical middle

```
var myDiv = $("#yourdiv");
var scrollto = myDiv.offset().top + (myDiv.height() / 2);
myDiv.animate({ scrollTop:  scrollto});
```

Comment: This computation did the trick: 

var scrollToMiddle = ($('#parent')[0].scrollHeight - $('#parent').height()) / 2;

$('#parent').scrollTop(scrollToMiddle);

Answer (score 1):

### JQuery - jump to vert/hori middle of scroll-div

#### vertical

```
$("#centralize-ver").click(function(){//centralize vertical
    var scrollableDivJ=$("#scroll-div");
    scrollableDivJ.scrollTop("1000000");//scroll to max
    var scrollHeight=scrollableDivJ.prop("scrollHeight");
    var diff=(scrollHeight-scrollableDivJ.scrollTop())/2;
    var middle=scrollHeight/2-diff;
    scrollableDivJ.scrollTop(middle);
});
```

#### horizontal

```
$("#centralize-hor").click(function(){//centralize horizontal
    var scrollableDivJ=$("#scroll-div");
    scrollableDivJ.scrollLeft("1000000");//scroll to max
    var scrollWidth=scrollableDivJ.prop("scrollWidth");
    var diff=(scrollWidth-scrollableDivJ.scrollLeft())/2;
    var middle=scrollWidth/2-diff;
    scrollableDivJ.scrollLeft(middle);
});
```

Replace "#scroll-div" with your div. "body" isn't working for me.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/der_hobler/3rdb3ggL/1/)

Thats the only solution that works properly for me. Actually its an 2h-try'n'error solution thats do its job pretty well. Maybe someone could explain why scrollTop is never reaching the value of prop("scrollheight") and the written calculation of diff and middle is necessary.